# Javascript Function To Change Div Style

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript script that gets the number of notifications from a php file and then displays the number into a div in the code.

```
<script>
//DISPLAY NUMBER OF UNREAD NOTIFICATIONS AND UPDATE EVERY 5 SECONDS
window.setInterval(function(){

   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");

}, 5000);

//WHEN THE BUTTON IS PRESSED THIS HAPPENS
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).show();
//GET THE NOTIFICATIONS 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myContent").load("getnotes.php?page=<? echo $page; ?>");
});

//RESET THE NUMBER OF UNREAD NOTIFICATIONS
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");
});


}

</script>

<div id='notes_number'> </div>
```

The number is in a bell shaped icon and when the number goes above 9 it becomes off center.  I'd like to have it set to `<div id='notes_number' style='right: 30px;'></div>` whenever the number gets above 9.

The issue I'm having is I have no idea how to get the number into a php variable so I can make the if else statement like so:

```
if ($thenumber <= "9") {
echo "<div id='notes_number'> </div>";
}
else {
echo "<div id='notes_number' style='right: 30px;'></div>";
}
```

CODE USED RECENTLY:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");

    var value = parseInt($('#notes_number').text());

    if(value > 9){
    $('#notes_number').css('right','30px');
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: how about giving your notes_number div "text-align:center" css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the html inside the bell always just put `<div id='notes_number'></div>` and then you can load the number in your javascript and add the style via jquery (if the number is over 9) like so: `$('#notes_number').css('right','30px');`

Comment: I edited my post to add the code that you mentioned but it's not working.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user2362601 The javascript works for me, possibly the css doesnt do quite what you are expecting? I've made up a jsfiddle example for you to see: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNtKU/) I also added the css absolute position to the div so you can see the difference in style and when it changes on each interval.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in the JavaScript layer. Instead of using `.load`, try using `.get` to inspect the value, and then assign styles accordingly.

```
window.setInterval(function(){

    $.get("getnumber.php", function(data) {

        $("#notes_number").val(parseInt(data,10));

        if(parseInt(data,10) > 9) {
            $("#notes_number").css('right','30px');
        } else {
            $("#notes_number").css('right','0');
        }

    });

}, 5000);
```

Comment: It did not display the number at all.  Can you edit the code to allow the number to be displayed?

Comment: got the number to display.  The code doesn't move the number if I go from 5 notifications to 10 notifications.  If there were 10 notifications on page load then it's moved but if there are less it is like normal and won't move once I receive 10 notifications.

Comment: Is your parent container set to `position:relative;` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same mark-up so:

```
<div id='notes_number'> </div>
```

then in your jquery you can grab the value:

```
var value = parseInt($('#notes_number').text());
```

and add a class if it is over 9

```
if(value > 9){
    $('#notes_number').addClass('largeNumber');
}
```

and let the CSS take care of the style rather than using inline styles via JS:

```
.largeNumber{
    right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: This didn't help.  It kept the number in the same spot.

Comment: I see, I was just using the styles you said you wanted to have, assuming they worked already and focusing on the JS. The javascript I used should work, but the styles must need to be changed from what you wanted. You might need to add position: absolute or relative to get it working, depending on the styles you have already. Difficult to correct this without seeing it in action.